# The directory to use npm to install package

Tags: node.js

I just get started on nodejs. I have installed nodejs and npm. Now, I want to install some packages like mongodb and express. As my default directory path in cmd is `C:\>Users\administrator`, do I need to make current folder as nodejs folder to run `npm install express/coffee-script` or I can just run this command under the default directory path mentioned above?

By the way, I always see the npm install command provided by others starts with a dollar sign, but I can only use the command without the dollar sign. So what does the dollar sign stand for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, npm will run in local mode, and install scripts into `./node_modules`. This is great if you need to `require` your scripts, as you'll do with Express.

Calling it with the `-g` option installs it globally, wherever node is installed (usually, on Linux, in /usr/local. This is great for packages that are meant to be run using the shell (for example, Supervisor).

Generally, if you want to develop a node.js application under `C:\foo\bar\myapp`, you will run `npm` from there.

FYI, the `$` sign is a general indication meaning that the following command is meant to be run on the command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. But I'm still a little bit confused. As I used the nodejs installer which has npm included it, I noticed that there is already a directory path under the nodejs folder which is node_modules\npm\node_modules. And there are already several modules under this path. So what I'm thinking is if I need another folder under the default folder provided by cmd to store some other modules. I should install all my modules in nodejs\node_modules\npm\mode_modules, right?

Comment: No. Node.JS directory has a `node_module` directory, which contains system-wide modules (installed with the `-g` switch). NPM is one of them. `node_modules\npm\node_modules` contains NPM dependencies. If you want to create your Node.JS app in the folder `myapp`, just go there with `cd myapp`, and run NPM from there. It can't be easier. Really.

Comment: So what you mean is it makes no sense to just install a package like express under the default path provided by cmd. I should install packages based on my applications. If I have several apps which all require express module, I should install this module for them respectively, right?

Comment: You're all right. As I said, installing apps under the global path generally only makes sense for packages meant to be used with the command line. You won't even be able to `require()` packages installed globally without additional steps.